# .htaccess redirect loop! All subdirectories to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root

I'm trying to redirect all subdirectories to the root of my website via .htaccess!
The code below works fine if I try to access a subdirectory ... but doesn't let me display the index page in the root because starts a loop of redirects!

```
RedirectMatch temp ^/.*$ http://localhost/
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all subdirectores to redirect to the home page, you would do something like this:

```
RedirectMatch temp ^/.+/.*$ http://localhost/
```

This will match any URI with two slashes in it, with at least one character between them.