# redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect temporally a domain to a subdomain, this is my code for .htaccess:

```
Redirect 302 / http://m.domain.com/
```

this works great, but i have some subdirectories like: http://domain.com/photos, the code above redirects this way: http://m.domain.com/photos
i have a lot of subdirs and sub-subdirs, how i can redirect successfully all the subdirs to the same subdomain? (http://m.domain.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post, I think it might help you. It looks like all you'd need to do is change your redirect to look something like:

`Redirect 302 ^/.+/.*$ http://m.domain.com/`

[.htaccess redirect loop! All subdirectories to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612729/htaccess-redirect-problem-all-subdirectories-to-root-solved)

Answer (score 0):

Hey, [this is a tool](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml) for generating the redirect code, and lets you choose how the final URL looks, without knowing regex. Might help you.